# How to control where YII flashes are placed?

Tags: yii

With [YII Flashes](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/21/how-to-work-with-flash-messages/) you can do this:

```
Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', "Data saved!");
```

However, when the flash appears on the page, it appears like so:

```
<div id="yw1">
  <div class="alert in alert-block fade alert-info"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
     MESSAGE
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I control WHERE this is placed? I don't see anything in layouts/main.php that controls this, yet they display?

Comment: are you using bootstrap extension or anything similar?

Comment: Have you come right with this @RD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They won't display anywhere unless you are calling them, a good example in the Yii default app is the *site/contact* view:

```
<?php if(Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('contact')): ?>    
    <div class="flash-success">
        <?php echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('contact'); ?>
    </div>    
<?php else: ?>
    ...
```

And the flash is set using the `setFlash` method

```
Yii::app()->user->setFlash('contact','Thank you for contacting us. We will respond to you as soon as possible.');
```

A possibility is that there may be a check in the Controller root class (*protected/components/Controller.php*), where someone may have written an `init()` function that checks for them. This would be called on every controller/action call so it may be there.

Another possibility is that whoever created the project edited the flash method in the framework folder (or possibly extended it), you could have a look there, it is in *framework/web/auth/CWebUser.php*

But as Mik said, try doing a text search in your project for **getFlash** or even just **flash**

Answer (score 1):

I would do a textsearch on user->getFlashes() in your views folder. You can output the messages at any place with this

```
<?php
    foreach(Yii::app()->user->getFlashes() as $key => $message) {
        echo '<div class="flash-' . $key . '">' . $message . "</div>\n";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Tried that. I can't find it anywhere. I think YII renders it by default somewhere, using something, but I don't know what. My solution so far is to read all flash in init() and then display them myself, but that's way more cumbersome than just moving the current placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

You, the developer,  need to display flash-messages. Yii does not do that for you.

You display them in a view, as shown by Eskimo and Mik, at a location of your own choosing . Yii could never do that, because Yii does not know the layout of your view.